# ajax type application/json shows Access-Control-Allow-Origin issue

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, authorization

I'm creating an API to connect with JIRA- TEMPO.

My request is working with the plugin in chrome "ARC" and its returning results. 
But When I send it via jQuery ajax its showing the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I have searched all of the solutions provided in StackOverflow it's not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
              $('.test').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                  method: 'GET',
                  type:  'Content-type',
                  dataType: 'application/json',
                  url: 'https://domain.atlassian.com/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs?dateFrom=YYYY-MM-DD&dateTo=YYYY-MM-DD',
                  beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa('username:password'));
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                  }
                }).done(function (msg) {
                  console.log(msg);
                }).fail(function () {
                  console.log("error");
                });
              });
            });
```

Kindly help to solve this problem. Is there any way to achieve this in PHP?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: in `https://domain.atlassian.com/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs?dateFrom=YYYY-MM-DD&dateTo=YYYY-MM-DD` You should set headers to allow remote server to reach it.

Comment: can you give me some example how its look like?

Answer (score 0):

Add this header into your script on `https://domain.atlassian.com/rest/tempo-timesheets/3/worklogs?dateFrom=YYYY-MM-DD&dateTo=YYYY-MM-DD`:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); // you can replace "*" by your domain name
```

Comment: @Jagadeesh Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719276/cors-with-php-headers